# cytoscape.js redraw after hiding nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm using Cytoscape JS to create a network. This is a large network and I need to hide some nodes to be more readable, but I can't redraw my network not including the hiding nodes.
How can I redraw using auto-layout after hiding some nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly what you mean.   An example would probably help.  There are different semantics for hidden versus removed elements, and it sounds like perhaps you want the elements removed.

Comment: I'm using a collapse/expand animation using hide/show methods. 
What I want is to, after hiding nodes, automatically redraw the nodes that are visible (not hidden) to make the network more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving similar problem by just having two instances of *Cytoscape.js* on a page. First is headless one (invisible, with no HTML-representation) that stores all data I have. Second one is visible and has a subset of objects I want to be visible and layouted at the moment.
Copying elements between instances is extremely easy, like:

```
cy.add(datacy.$('#elem1'));
```